# Retrieve Data Properties of An Individual using OWL API in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, owl, ontology

I want to retrieve all data properties set for an individual of any class using owl api. The code i have used is

```
OWLNamedIndividual inputNoun = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(prefix + "Cow"));


            for (OWLDataProperty prop: inputNoun.getDataPropertiesInSignature())
            {
               System.out.println("the properties for Cow are " + prop);    //line 1
            }
```

This code compiles with success but line 1 print nothing at all. What should be the correct syntax. Have thoroughly googled and couldnt find any thing worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OWLNamedIndividual::getDataPropertiesInSignature()` does not return the properties for which the individual has a filler, it returns the properties that appear in the object itself. For an individual this is usually empty. The method is on the `OWLObject` interface, which covers things like class and property expressions and ontologies, for which it has a more useful output.

If you want the data properties with an actual filler for an individual, use `OWLOntology::getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms(OWLIndividual)`, like this:

```
OWLNamedIndividual input = ...
Set<OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom> properties=ontology.getDataPropertyAssertionAxioms(input);
for (OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom ax: properties) {
    System.out.println(ax.getProperty());
}
```